# Handling dynamic pages in Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I have tried handling this a few different ways. My current code is as below, and the implicit waits do not seem to work in the for loop? Previously I tried a different time of wait condition but it resulted in a stale element.

Essentially what happens is I need to click into the box with class recordContainer and then this activates a text input (.ui-inputfield). There is an autocomplete form that pops up, however my code executes too fast and therefore doesn't acknowledge / click the autocomplete option.

Alternatively if I slow it down, I seem to get a stale element error after it locates the first input box.
Hope this makes sense. I need to slow it down and handle the stale element error.

```
records = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector(".recordContainer")

i=0
for a in records:
    a.click()
    browser.implicitly_wait(2)
    if i>=1 and i < 4:
        text = a.find_element_by_class_name("ui-inputfield")
        text.send_keys(players[i-1])
        browser.implicitly_wait(2)
        text.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
    i = i+1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "valid xpath")) 
        )
```

you can use any locator of your choice

this will explicitly wait for 10 seconds and then throw a stale element exception
if the presence of the elements is not detected.
You can check the documentation on explicit waits in selenium